# 自作クラスをマップのキーにする方法

Tags: java

以下のように`map`のキーに自作クラスを指定することはありますでしょうか。
ただし、自作クラスは`equals`と`hashCode`はオーバーライドせず、
あくまで参照アドレスをキーにする感じです。

```
Person p1 = new Person("AAA",10);
Person p2 = new Person("BBB",20);

Map<Person, Boolean> map  = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(p1, true);
map.put(p2, false);

map.get(p1);
map.get(p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

ご質問の趣旨は「企業やオープンソースプロジェクトなどの大規模な開発現場で、`map`のキーに自作クラスを指定することはあるのか」という理解でよろしいでしょうか。

理解が合っているならば、回答は「**ごく普通に数え切れないほど使われている**(はず※)」です。
※統計を取ったわけではないのでぼかしていますが、私は自作クラスを`Map`のキーにするソースコードを複数見かけたことがあります。

特に必要性がなければ`equals`のオーバーライドは行いません。
例えば`Person`クラスの`name`と`age`変数が同一のインスタンスは`equals`を`true`にしたいならばオーバーライドしますが、インスタンスの同一性を確認する用途ならば継承元の`Object`クラスの`equals`メソッドをそのまま利用すれば事足りますのでオーバーライドは不要です。